# How to resolve two fields in one @ResolveField method

Tags: graphql, nestjs, typeorm

I have orders resolver, like this one(thats an example, not actually problem):

```
@Resolver(() => OrderEntity)
export class OrderResolver {
  constructor(
    private readonly orderService: OrderService,
    private readonly usersService: UsersService,
  ) {}

.................

  @ResolveField('users', () => [UsersEntity])
  async users(@Parent() order: OrderEntity): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return await this.usersService.findAllByOrderId(order.id);
  }

  @ResolveField('usersCount', () => Int)
  async usersCount(@Parent() order: OrderEntity): Promise<number> {
    const users = await this.usersService.findAllByOrderId(order.id);
    return users.lenght; // i can't use like this: order.users.lenght, couse it's still undefined 
  }
}
```

And there are i call `userService.findAllByOrderId` method two times, because i can't use order.users from context in this method, as its still undefined

So how can i write one @ResolveField method for both fields: **order.users** and **order.usersCount**, or how to call **usersCount** method when **order.users** are already existing?

Thank's a lot for any answers!

I call one method 2 times, instead 1, how can i optimize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need to do a query to get the number of the `noOfUsers` ?. Cant you just call the `async users` function that returns `UserEntity[]` and then get the length of the array that is returned `.length`

or

If you really need to return the noOfUsers as an int then you can create a wrapper object and put the 2 fields in that e.g.

```js
export class UserResponse {
  users: Array<UserEntity>;
  noOfUsers: int
}
```

Then you can only have 1 method that returns both fields:

```js
@ResolveField('users', () => [UserResponse])
  async users(@Parent() order: OrderEntity): Promise<UserResponse> {
    const userEntities: Array<UserEntity> = await this.usersService.findAllByOrderId(order.id);
    
    const response: UserResponse = {
      users: userEntities,
      noOfUsers: userEntities.length
    }
    
    return response;
  }
```